# Login screen only first time in native app in sencha

Tags: sqlite, cordova, extjs, authentication, sencha-touch

i am working on a **native app in sencha touch**. i want to create a login view which should be visible only first time. any suggestion how to solve it.

Activation.js

```
Ext.define('FOS.view.Activation', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias: "widget.activationview",
    requires: ['Ext.form.FieldSet', 'Ext.form.Password', 'Ext.Label', 'Ext.Img', 'Ext.util.DelayedTask'],
    config: {
        title: 'Login',
        items: [

            {
                xtype: 'label',
                html: 'Activation failed. Please enter the correct credentials.',
                itemId: 'activationFailedLabel',
                hidden: true,
                hideAnimation: 'fadeOut',
                showAnimation: 'fadeIn',
                style: 'color:#990000;margin:5px 0px;'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                title: ' ',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        placeHolder: 'Enter Agency Id',
                        itemId: 'agencyIdTextField',
                        name: 'agencyIdTextField',
            label: 'Agency Id',
                        labelWidth: '40%',
                        //required: true
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        placeHolder: 'Enter App Id',
                        itemId: 'appIdTextField',
                        name: 'appIdTextField',
            label: 'App Id',
                        labelWidth: '40%',
                       // required: true
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                itemId: 'activationButton',
                ui: 'action',
                padding: '10px',
                text: 'Activate'
            }
         ],
        listeners: [{
            delegate: '#activationButton',
            event: 'tap',
            fn: 'onActivationButtonTap'
        }]
    },
    onActivationButtonTap: function () {

        var me = this,
            agencyidField = me.down('#agencyIdTextField'),
            appidField = me.down('#appIdTextField'),
            label = me.down('#activationFailedLabel'),
            agencyid = agencyidField.getValue(),
            appid = appidField.getValue();

        label.hide();

        // Using a delayed task in order to give the hide animation above
        // time to finish before executing the next steps.
        var task = Ext.create('Ext.util.DelayedTask', function () {

            label.setHtml('');

            me.fireEvent('activationCommand', me, agencyid, appid);

            agencyidField.setValue('');
            appidField.setValue('');
        });

        task.delay(500);

    },
    showActivationFailedMessage: function (message) {
        var label = this.down('#activationFailedLabel');
        label.setHtml(message);
        label.show();
    }
});
```

Login.js

```
Ext.define('FOS.view.Login', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias: "widget.loginview",
    requires: ['Ext.form.FieldSet', 'Ext.form.Password', 'Ext.Label', 'Ext.Img', 'Ext.util.DelayedTask'],
    config: {
        title: 'Login',
        items: [

            {
                xtype: 'label',
                html: 'Login failed. Please enter the correct credentials.',
                itemId: 'signInFailedLabel',
                hidden: true,
                hideAnimation: 'fadeOut',
                showAnimation: 'fadeIn',
                style: 'color:#990000;margin:5px 0px;'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                title: ' ',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        placeHolder: 'Enter UserName',
                        itemId: 'userNameTextField',
                        name: 'userNameTextField',
            label: 'UserName',
                        labelWidth: '40%',
                        //required: true
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'passwordfield',
                        placeHolder: 'Enter Password',
                        itemId: 'passwordTextField',
                        name: 'passwordTextField',
            label: 'Password',
                        labelWidth: '40%',
                       // required: true
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                itemId: 'logInButton',
                ui: 'action',
                padding: '10px',
                text: 'Log In'
            }
         ],
        listeners: [{
            delegate: '#logInButton',
            event: 'tap',
            fn: 'onLogInButtonTap'
        }]
    },
    onLogInButtonTap: function () {

        var me = this,
            usernameField = me.down('#userNameTextField'),
            passwordField = me.down('#passwordTextField'),
            label = me.down('#signInFailedLabel'),
            username = usernameField.getValue(),
            password = passwordField.getValue();

        label.hide();

        // Using a delayed task in order to give the hide animation above
        // time to finish before executing the next steps.
        var task = Ext.create('Ext.util.DelayedTask', function () {

            label.setHtml('');

            me.fireEvent('signInCommand', me, username, password);

            usernameField.setValue('');
            passwordField.setValue('');
        });

        task.delay(500);

    },
    showSignInFailedMessage: function (message) {
        var label = this.down('#signInFailedLabel');
        label.setHtml(message);
        label.show();
    }
});
```

MainMenu.js

```
Ext.define('FOS.view.MainMenu', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    requires: ['Ext.TitleBar'],
    alias: 'widget.mainmenuview',
    config: {
        layout: {
            type: 'fit'
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            title: 'Main Menu',
            docked: 'top',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Log Off',
                    itemId: 'logOffButton',
                    align: 'right'
                }
            ]
        }],
        listeners: [{
            delegate: '#logOffButton',
            event: 'tap',
            fn: 'onLogOffButtonTap'
        }]
    },
    onLogOffButtonTap: function () {
        this.fireEvent('onSignOffCommand');
    }
});
```

controller

```
Ext.define('FOS.controller.Login', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

   config: {
        refs: {
            loginView: 'loginview',
            mainMenuView: 'mainmenuview',
        activationView: 'activationview'
        },
        control: {
        activationView: {
                activationCommand: 'onActivationCommand'
            },
               loginView: {
                   signInCommand: 'onSignInCommand'
            },
            mainMenuView: {
                onSignOffCommand: 'onSignOffCommand'
            }
        }
    },

    // Session token

   // sessionToken: null,

    // Transitions
    getSlideLeftTransition: function () {
        return { type: 'slide', direction: 'left' };
    },

    getSlideRightTransition: function () {
        return { type: 'slide', direction: 'right' };
    },

onActivationCommand: function (view, agencyid, appid) {

        console.log('AgencyId: ' + agencyid + '\n' + 'AppId: ' + appid);

        var me = this,
            activationView = me.getActivationView();

        if (agencyid.length === 0 || appid.length === 0) {

            activationView.showActivationFailedMessage('Please enter your Agency Id and App Id.');
            return;
        }

        activationView.setMasked({
            xtype: 'loadmask',
            message: 'Activating...'
        });

            me.activationSuccess();     //Just simulating success.

    },

    activationSuccess: function () {
        console.log('Activated.');
        var activationView = this.getActivationView();
        loginView = this.getLoginView();
        activationView.setMasked(false);

        Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(loginView, this.getSlideLeftTransition());
    },

    onSignInCommand: function (view, username, password) {

        console.log('Username: ' + username + '\n' + 'Password: ' + password);

        var me = this,
            loginView = me.getLoginView();

        if (username.length === 0 || password.length === 0) {

            loginView.showSignInFailedMessage('Please enter your User Name and Password.');
            return;
        }

        loginView.setMasked({
            xtype: 'loadmask',
            message: 'Signing In...'
        });

      /*  Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: '../../services/login.ashx',
            method: 'post',
            params: {
                user: username,
                pwd: password
            },
            success: function (response) {

                var loginResponse = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);

                if (loginResponse.success === "true") {
                    // The server will send a token that can be used throughout the app to confirm that the user is authenticated.
                    me.sessionToken = loginResponse.sessionToken;*/
                    me.signInSuccess();     //Just simulating success.
               /* } else {
                    me.singInFailure(loginResponse.message);
                }
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                me.sessionToken = null;
                me.singInFailure('Login failed. Please try again later.');
            }
        });*/
    },

    signInSuccess: function () {
        console.log('Signed in.');
        var loginView = this.getLoginView();
        mainMenuView = this.getMainMenuView();
        loginView.setMasked(false);

        Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(mainMenuView, this.getSlideLeftTransition());
    },
/*
    singInFailure: function (message) {
        var loginView = this.getLoginView();
        loginView.showSignInFailedMessage(message);
        loginView.setMasked(false);
    },*/

    onSignOffCommand: function () {

        var me = this;

       /* Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: '../../services/logoff.ashx',
            method: 'post',
            params: {
                sessionToken: me.sessionToken
            },
            success: function (response) {

                // TODO: You need to handle this condition.
            },
           failure: function (response) {

                // TODO: You need to handle this condition.
            }
        });*/

        Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(this.getLoginView(), this.getSlideRightTransition());
    }
});
```

app.js

```
//<debug>
Ext.Loader.setPath({
    'Ext': 'touch/src',
    'FOS': 'app'
});
//</debug>

Ext.application({
    controllers: ["Login"],

    name: 'FOS',

    requires: [
        'Ext.MessageBox'
    ],

    views: ['Activation','Login','MainMenu'],



    icon: {
        '57': 'resources/icons/Icon.png',
        '72': 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad.png',
        '114': 'resources/icons/Icon@2x.png',
        '144': 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad@2x.png'
    },

    isIconPrecomposed: true,

    startupImage: {
        '320x460': 'resources/startup/320x460.jpg',
        '640x920': 'resources/startup/640x920.png',
        '768x1004': 'resources/startup/768x1004.png',
        '748x1024': 'resources/startup/748x1024.png',
        '1536x2008': 'resources/startup/1536x2008.png',
        '1496x2048': 'resources/startup/1496x2048.png'
    },

    launch: function() {
        // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
        Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();

        // Initialize the main view

    Ext.Viewport.add([
         { xtype: 'activationview'},
             { xtype: 'mainmenuview' },
         { xtype: 'loginview' }
     ]);
    },

    onUpdated: function() {
        Ext.Msg.confirm(
            "Application Update",
            "This application has just successfully been updated to the latest version. Reload now?",
            function(buttonId) {
                if (buttonId === 'yes') {
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            }
        );
    }
});
```

i want this activation view only one time.
web services are not availabale yet....

Comment: Can you share any code you tried with us?

Comment: thanks for reply....i am sharing my code. i am new in sencha plz help me......

Answer (score 7):

Basically, what you looking for is something similar to **Remember Me** or **SSO** (single sign-on) feature that is available on most of the websites and native apps. I myself needed this in one of my app recently.

With sencha, you can use HTML5 storage. Once user is logged in successfully, store certain user details like login status, access token, user id etc into HTML5 database. You can easily store upto 5MB of data in it and since sencha runs on modern web browsers like webkit, you can use that api and do stuff  with it.

So to the point, I've created a model having various fields like user id, login status and access token in my app. For instance you can have model something like -

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Userinfo',{
    extend:'Ext.data.Model',
    config:{
        identifier: 'uuid',
        store:'MyApp.store.Userinfo',
        fields:[                 
           {name: 'id', type: 'string' },
           {name: 'userid', type: 'string' },
           {name:'login_status',type:'string'},
           {name:'access_token',type:'string'}
        ]    
    }        
});
```

You can add number of field as per your requirement and choose suitable types for each field. But your model should have a unique identifier. With ST2.0 you can use `identifier:'uuid'` to assign unique identifier to your storage.

Then comes store, it can be like -

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Userinfo',{
   extend:'Ext.data.Store',   
   config:{
       model:'MyApp.model.Userinfo',
       autoLoaded:true,
       autoLoad: true,
       autoSave:true,
       proxy:{
           type:'localstorage',
           id:'userinfo'
       }
   }
});
```

Then finally, when the login is successful, you can add data into your localstorage with -

```
  var userInfoData=Ext.getStore('Userinfo');                                
  userInfoData.removeAll();
  userInfoData.getProxy().clear();
  userInfoData.add({userid:'user_id_to_store',login_status:"true",access_token:'generated_access_token'});
  userInfoData.sync();
```

And at the end, in your `app.js` , check for a entry into this localstorage and validate access token for reliability. So in `launch` method,

```
var userInfoData=Ext.getStore('Userinfo');              
if(null!=userInfoData.getAt(0)){
    var status = userInfoData.getAt(0).get('login_status');
    var user_id=userInfoData.getAt(0).get('userid');
    var access_token = userInfoData.getAt(0).get('access_token');   

    //validate access token, check user id and status and load your next view that comes after login    

}else{
    // if reached here, that means user is not logged in.
    // load your login view.  
}
```

I couldn't read your whole code and edit it. But this is what I've used and it's working without any trouble up till now. You can alter it easily as per your app and requirements.

---

**NOTICE**

This code is more than a year old. So it might not work on latest ST version (not tested).
But idea is same. Cheers. :)

Comment: Is this localstorage works in nativa apps? If I packaging my sencha app to .apk or to iOS app, the localstorage will work?

Comment: @HossamGhareeb localstorage mentioned in answer is **HTML5 LocalStorage**. Yes it is available in both ios and android but you can use it if your app is a web app running in a webview only. For a native app w/o webview you can use sqlite or in case of ios you can use core data. As state in your comment your app is *sencha packaged app*, then YES, you can use HTML5 localstorage with API given by sencha.