# Sencha Touch LOcal Storage on Mobile Apps

Tags: sencha-touch, local-storage

I am planning to use Sencha Touch for an application of my company. I read that local storage stores data on client's browser. MY problem is when I build the code to native app using Sencha CMD how does the local storage work? What is the alternative of local storage to keep some data suppose user details (so that user doesn't need to login always).

Advance Thanks

Comment: you may find this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642944/login-screen-only-first-time-in-native-app-in-sencha/14653599#14653599 useful.

Answer (score 2):

### localStorage

Is a very easy to use interface that works *synchronous*. It stores strings (you can `JSON.stringify` other Javascript objects) as key-value pairs and you just set the value with a key in this way:

```
localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
```

To read:

```
var value = localStorage.getItem('key');
```

which returns `value` or `null` if key wasn't found in the storage.

You *can* use it as an object:

```
localStorage['key'] = 'value';
var value = localStorage['key'];
```

however, this is not the recommended approach. In this case `undefined` will be returned for non-existing items.

More details:
http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/PR-webstorage-20130409/
http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

### IndexedDB

Database that sort of replaces the now deprecated `Web SQL`. It works asynchronous and is a bit harder to understand as it uses stores, requests and transactions to deal with the data.

You can store any kind of objects in `IndexedDB` (Javascript objects, Blobs (files)).

You can also request storage space. User will be alerted if you need more than 5 mb (5 mb is not defined, but seem to be the limit most browsers set before asking user for permission).

See here for details on how you can use it:
http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/

### Web SQL

Although, as mentioned, deprecated it is still supported in browsers such as Safari. Is a database that works with SQL-queries and request, and works asynchronous.

Here are more details:
http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/
http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/

### File API

Currently only supported in Chrome. Is a virtual file-system that works asynchronous as `IndexedDB` but is intended for large files (video and audio files etc.) but can just as easily be used for storing other data.

You can store any kind of objects in File API as Blobs (files). As it is a virtual file system you can navigate using folders.

You can also request storage space here as well (quota).

For details:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/
http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/

And of course there is `cookies` and for IE `UserData`, but these are very limited.

Comment: Does not answer the question as it does not show how to use localstore in Sencha Touch.

Answer (score 1):

This example demonstrates how to use local storage with Sencha Touch model objects:

- http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/06/sencha-touch-local-storage-example.html

If you're wanting to switch & sync data from online to offline you might also be interested in this example:

- https://www.robertkehoe.com/2012/11/sencha-touch-2-localstorage-example/